# Sending Message to AutoIt for a VB6 Listbox and Finding String?

Tags: vb6, listbox, autoit, sendmessage

2
   I went through the forums and other related question, but did not get much help.
   My question is related to sending Message to controls using AutoIt. In the following code I am trying to find the index of Text that I intended to search("L20"). The application is written in VB and the same SendMessage through VB works. I believe the below SendMessage has some issue. Please help me finding the issue.

```
$WindowName = "Form1"
$WindowText = ""
WinWait("[CLASS:ThunderRT6FormDC]")
Local $hListBox1 = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:ThunderRT6FormDC]", "", "ThunderRT6ListBox1")
Local $hListBox2 = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:ThunderRT6FormDC]", "", "ThunderRT6ListBox2")
WinActivate( $WindowName, $WindowText )
ControlClick("[CLASS:ThunderRT6FormDC]", "", "ThunderRT6ListBox2")
MsgBox(0, "ControlGetHandle Example", $hListBox1 & " - " & $LB_FINDSTRING & " - " & -1 & " - " & "L20")
MsgBox(0, "ControlGetHandle Example", $hListBox2 & " - " & $LB_FINDSTRING & " - " & -1 & " - " & "L20")
Local $sText = "L20"
Local $obj1 = DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "SendMessageA", "hwnd", $hListBox1, "UINT",     $LB_FINDSTRING, "WPARAM", -1, "wstr", $sText)
Local $obj2 = DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "SendMessageA", "hwnd", $hListBox2, "UINT", $LB_FINDSTRING, "WPARAM", -1, "wstr", $sText)
;Local $obj1 = _SendMessageA($hListBox1, $LB_FINDSTRING, -1, "L20")
;Local $obj2 = _SendMessageA($hListBox2, $LB_FINDSTRING, -1, "L20")
MsgBox(0, "ControlGetHandle Example", "The control handle of ThunderRT6ListBox1 is: " & $obj1 & $obj2)
```

The following vb6 version works in VB6 application

```
If FindExactMatch Then
    GetListBoxIndex = SendMessage(hWnd, LB_FINDSTRINGEXACT, StartIndex, SearchKey)
Else
    GetListBoxIndex = SendMessage(hWnd, LB_FINDSTRING, StartIndex, SearchKey)
End If
```

Comment: Which line of code produces the error?

Comment: No line produces error. Just that it doesnt return index.

Comment: In your question you said it has some error, then your comment says it doesn't error. Can you be more specific on what isn't working?

Comment: There are no compilation error. The script itself has issues in send message.

Comment: I modified the post correctly and changed word error to issue

Comment: @Naresh I think you would be able to find what is producing the "issue" you are having by error trapping the functions that you are using in your script. Checking the helpfile - (http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions.htm) and placing these will greatly help you understand what is going on through your code.